# Glassfish 3.1 application.wadl reorder elements

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, soapui, wadl

I am currently using Glassfish to host a bunch of RESTful Web Services.  Glassfish is very helpful and generates a wadl for me.  The problem that I'm having is the wadl it generates puts all the resources in a random order.

Our wonderful QA folks (and us developers) use SoapUI to consume the wadl and manually call the web serivices for testing purposes.  This process has become frustrating because it is hard to find the web service we want to call because it is not alphabetized.  To make it worse every time we add or change a web service we have to re import the wadl into SoapUI which changes the order of the web services.

I have done a lot of digging and have not found a configuration file or property that will tell glassfish to order the wadl before publishing it.  I also could not find a way to get SoapUI to reorder the web services to be in alphabetical order.  The solution that I came up with is to use JAXB to convert the wadl to Java objects, reorder the Java objects, then convert it back to Java.

What all of this boils down to, is there a way to get Glassfish 3.1 to reorder the wadl to be in alphabetical order or get SoapUI to display the web services in alphabetical order?